# Calculating midpoint index in binary search

Tags: c, search

So, the correct way of calculating `mid` in a binary search is `mid = low + ((high - low) / 2)` in order to handle overflow errors.

My implementation uses unsigned 64 bit variables and I don't ever see a situation where my arrays get so big so as to cause an overflow. Do I still need use the above implementation or can I use `mid = (low + high) / 2`

What's best practice here?

Comment: @EdHeal I think that these work out to be the same algebraically and even with rounding factored in.

Comment: @EdHeal I apologize if I'm missing something, but don't those come out the same in both cases?

Comment: `low + (high - low) / 2` is not guaranteed to be safe either. I work on code that supports negative indices. A positive `high` and negative `low` could overflow `high - low`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If there is no possibility of overflow, the overflow-safe way of computing the midpoint is technically unnecessary: you can use the unsafe formula if you wish. However, it's probably a good idea to keep it there anyway, in case that your program gets modified some day to break your assumptions. I think that adding a single CPU instruction to make your code future-proof is a great investment in maintainability of your code.

Comment: Also: you never know when somebody is going to cut and paste your code and use it elsewhere, where your assumptions don't fly. Maybe they will run it on a 32-bit machine, and use huge arrays - or something. If you know a programming idiom that *always* works, don't replace it with one that occasionally works unless there's a good reason. (Better than saving a few keystrokes or 2 machine instructions in a loop) just my $0.02

Answer (score 9):

Check this article [Nearly All Binary Searches and Mergesorts are Broken](http://googleresearch.blogspot.ru/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html)

Better practice (for today)

> Probably faster, and arguably as clear is:
>    6:             int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;

and after that :

> In C and C++ (where you don't have the >>> operator), you can do this:
>    6:             mid = ((unsigned int)low + (unsigned int)high)) >> 1;

And at the end :

> Update 17 Feb 2008: Thanks to Antoine Trux, Principal Member of Engineering Staff at Nokia Research Center Finland for pointing out that the original proposed fix for C and C++ (Line 6), was not guaranteed to work by the relevant C99 standard (INTERNATIONAL STANDARD - ISO/IEC - 9899 - Second edition - 1999-12-01, 3.4.3.3), which says that if you add two signed quantities and get an overflow, the result is undefined. The older C Standard, C89/90, and the C++ Standard are both identical to C99 in this respect. Now that we've made this change, we know that the program is correct;)

Bottom line, there always will be a case when it won't work

Answer (score 7):

Don Knuth's method works perfectly through a bitmask with no possibility of an overflow:

```
return (low & high) + ((low ^ high) >> 1)
```

EDIT: `low + high = (low ^ high) + (low & high) << 1`

page 19, The Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 4, Donald E. Knuth

Answer (score 0):

> So, the correct way of calculating `mid` in a binary search is `mid = low + ((high - low) / 2)` in order to handle overflow errors.

This is incorrect. Consider `low = 18 * pow(10, 18)` and `high = 1 * pow(10, 18)`.
Both `mid = (low + high) / 2` and your method overflow, yielding `276627963145224192` instead of the correct `9500000000000000000`.

Comment: why is high > low? It should be impossible.