# Is there any way to make my binary search algorithm more efficient and also, is it correct?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I started to learn divide and conquer and I wanted to test my skills by trying to write my own binarySearch.

For my examples my algorithm works, but I wonder if there might be any case in which it doesn't, because it is pretty simple (compared to other binary search algorithms) and I don't really feel confident in it.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int binarySearch(int arr[], int low, int high, int n)
{
    int i = (high + low) / 2;
    if (arr[i] == n)
    {
        return i;
    }
    else
    {
        if (arr[i] > n)
        {
            return binarySearch(arr, low, i - 1, n);
        }
        if (arr[i] < n)
        {
            return binarySearch(arr, i + 1, high, n);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 }, n = 7;
    cout<<binarySearch(arr, 0, 6, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Also, can I make it more efficient in any way? (without combining it with other algorithsm - just by doing tweaks)

Thanks. I'm sorry for my kind of vague question, but I want to learn, and the best way to do so is by asking for review from better programmers :)

Edit after @1201ProgramAlarm's comment:
I forgot about the case in which n is not in the array. Here's the edited code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int binarySearch(int arr[], int low, int high, int n)
{
    if (low <= high)
    {
        int i = (high + low) / 2;
        if (arr[i] == n)
        {
            return i;
        }
        else
        {
            if (arr[i] > n)
            {
                return binarySearch(arr, low, i - 1, n);
            }
            if (arr[i] < n)
            {
                return binarySearch(arr, i + 1, high, n);
            }
        }
    }   
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[10]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 }, n = 7;
    cout<<binarySearch(arr, 0, 6, 9);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Consider what happens if `n` is not in `arr`.

Comment: Your midpoint calculation is susceptible to overflow issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101110/calculating-midpoint-index-in-binary-search

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm fixed it, thanks :) any other suggestions?

Comment: I recommend posting to [codereview.se] if your code is working.

Comment: @NathanOliver I will check that post tommorow, right now I'm too tired to follow lol. Thanks a lot for the info though :)

Comment: It doesn't work if the input sequence is constant or you only have reference-to-const to it. However, a codereview is a very good idea, there's quite some potential for improvement.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I didn't even know it existed. Thanks a lot

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt i will post on code review. Thanks.

Comment: Recursion is not advisable for large arrays, as it takes up *stack* space, and *stack* space is usually small compared to other memory areas.  In other words, your function could cause StackOverflow for larger arrays.

Comment: you can do iterative bin search instead recursive one and also using integer arithmetic to SAR the mantissa and perhaps even exponent if needed of your float/double.... instead of using floating `(hi+low)/2`