# how to use binary search on string

Tags: c++, binary-search

i'm currently working on a problem in some competitive code site, it's a program to search phone number by inputting the person's name

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int binarySearch(string arr[], string x,int n)
    {
        int l = 0 ;
        int r = n - 1;
        while (l <= r)
        {
            int m = l + (r - l) / 2;
 
        int res;
        if (arr[m].compare(x) == 0){
            res = 0;
        }
            
             
 
            if (res == 0){
                return m;
            }
                
 
            if (x > (arr[m])){
                l = m + 1;
            }   
            else{
                r = m - 1;
            }
                
        }
 
        return -1;
    }
 
  
int main() 
{ 
    int N, K, output;
    cin >> N >> K;
    string name[N];
    string input;
    string sarch[K];
    string number[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cin >> name[i];
        cin >> number[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
    {
       cin >> sarch[i];

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
    {
        output = binarySearch(name, sarch[i], N);
        if(output >= 0){
            cout << number[output] << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "NIHIL" << endl;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

for example if i input

> 7 2
>  agung 572381
>  ani 111111
>  budi 222222
>  dengklek
> 696969
>  ganesh 987123
>  gareng 429088
>  hadi 682385
> budi
>  nyancoder

output will be

> 222222
> NIHIL

for some reason i got WA and 0 pts and i've tried few times and it works fine can any of you pin point the bug and give solution

i'm telling you it works fine (even in my cmd): https://ibb.co/QX9D6yY

but why it outputs 696969 in other compiler: https://ibb.co/ZWcRcjH

Comment: and what do you expect? When fixing your VLAs (they are not available in C++) I get `696969 696969` as output: https://ideone.com/y0QX4G

Comment: You should use string.compare - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158894/differences-between-c-string-and-compare

Comment: @mch because you only do the actual string comparison once, plus you have options available such as ignore case.  You then use the integer result of the comparison twice (is-equal then is-greater-than).  In this case `operator==` and `operator>` will be called on the string, which is inefficient.

Comment: @Den-Jason i have and I still got WA and 0 pts is the compiler wacky or??

Comment: Are you sure you're not going out of bounds when the search term is higher than all of the values?

Comment: PS: `res = arr[m].compare(x)` ;)

Comment: why write manually binary search? why not use std::lower_bound? or even use std::map or, std::unordered_map as key-value container which would map name to phone?

Comment: @Den-Jason i'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Oh, and `m = l + (r - l) / 2;` probably should be `m = (l + r) / 2;`

Comment: @ivan.ukr ok i'll try

Comment: @Den-Jason No, it shouldn't ;)

Comment: @Den-Jason Oh, now I see where your numbers come from. Please note that OP's ([correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101110/calculating-midpoint-index-in-binary-search)) formula is `middle = left + (right - left) / 2`, not `middle = left + (right - 1) / 2`. This is the biggest problem when using one-letter variable names, they can be misread.

Comment: @Bob__ LOL yes I just spotted that myself :D  Thanks for the link; that's an interesting corner case to watch out for when doing 8-bit stuff.