# Can I use condition front != end in binary search?

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-search

We use `while(front <= end)` in binary search. Can I use the condition `while(front != end)` like in the code here? I cannot find a case where it fails.

```
class BinarySearch {
public:
    int bin_search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        int count = nums.size();
        int front = 0;
        int end = count - 1;

        if(nums[0]==target){return 0;}
        while(front!=end){

            int mid = (end + front)/2;
            // cout<<mid<<endl;
            if(nums[front] == target){return front;}
            else if(nums[end] == target){return end;}


            else if(nums[mid]==target){return mid;}

            else if(nums[mid]<target){
                front = mid+1;
            }

            else if(nums[mid]>target){
                end = mid - 1;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
};
```

Since I am checking the condition for `nums[front]` and `nums[end]` in every while loop I don't think this code should fail. On test cases I am getting correct answers. Is there any case where it will fail?

Comment: FYI, are you aware that there is [std::lower_bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and `std::upper_bound` that does this already?

Comment: `int mid = (end + front)/2;` -- What if `end + front` overflows what an `int` can hold?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, I am. I was just asking if the code I have written is correct or not.

Comment: `if(nums[0]==target){return 0;}` is incorrect if the container is empty. https://godbolt.org/z/7rKTrhr7d

Comment: [Calculating midpoint index in binary search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101110/calculating-midpoint-index-in-binary-search).  Thus your binary search is broken in at least two ways -- empty vector and miscalculation of the midpoint when a large number of items are in the vector.

Comment: Small note, for bin_search arguments : `vector<int>& nums` -> `const vector<int>& nums`, because find shouldn't even be able to modify content of nums.

Comment: The way `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` does it is better, because it only requires one comparison operator: `<`.  Not a problem for simple numeric types, but for more complex types providing another operator could be a burden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No, this is not a valid implementation. Why?

Assume `vector<int> nums = {1, 2, 5, 8}` and `int target = 3`. Let's see how a binary search with `!=` instead of `<=` would work. (or rather wouldn't)

### After the first iteration:

`front` = 1
`end` = 3
`mid` = 1

### After the second iteration:

`front` = 2
`end` = 3
`mid` = 2

### After the third iteration (and all other infinite interations):

`front` = 2
`end` = 1
`mid` = 2

Here `<=` would finish the loop, but since we are using `!=` you are stuck in a permanent loop.

## So exactly now, why doesn't it work?

Assumption that left and right in binary search at some point must equal is false. If it was true, then for every `N` and `M` (where N represents `front` and M `end`), such as `N < M`: `(N+M)/2+1 <= M` and `(N+M)/2-1 >= N`. After transformation we get `N + 2 <= M`, which is not true when `N` and `M` are one index apart. If this happens at any point in a binary search with `!=` instead of `<=` you will get an endless loop.

## Okay, but can we get around this?

As with everything *yes*, if specific edge cases are added, but unless the only reason for doing that is getting to improve understanding of binary search, do not.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has a number of minor problems in it that could lead to incorrect results.

I'll rewrite it, then I'll describe why I made each change.

```
std::size_t bin_search(std::vector<int> const& nums, int target) {
```

1. Take your container by `const&`.
2. Return a `std::size_t` not an `int`; `int` is often 32 bit even on 64 bit machines, and vectors of size 2^31-1 can be handled by modern computers.  By returning an `int`, you limit what your algorithm can handle.  On 64 bit machines, `size_t` is 64 bits, which is going to be more than enough to deal with any `std::vector` for at least the next few decades if not centuries.

   auto front = nums.begin();
   auto end = nums.end();
   by using iterators instead of indexes and by using half-open intervals, a bunch of benefits are produced.

Half open intervals handle empty intervals very naturally - with the start and end being equal.

Iterators instead of indexes are both a bit faster, and prevent you from mixing up your value space with your iteration space.

We also cut the "check the 0 element".  An empty vector dies here, and your algorithm should be correct without a hard-coded check here.

```
  while(front!=end) {
```

we keep this the same.  Note that `!=` will work fine.

```
    auto mid = front + (end-front)/2;
```

this is a subtle difference.  Instead of adding the indexes of end and front and dividing by two, which can lead to out-of-gamut problems, we take half the distance between them (which is limited by 64 bits), halve it, and add it back to front.

Because we are actually using iterators, this is also legal - iterator subtraction on (random access) iterators produces distance integrals, which can be halved, and adding that back to an iterator produces an iterator again.

```
    if (*mid == target) { return mid-nums.begin(); }
    if (target > *mid) { front = std::next(mid); continue; }
    if (target < *mid) { end = mid; continue; }
```

here I change the exit condition.  I only check mid!

We do a 3 way comparison.  This is useful because I can call `<=>` in more modern version of C++ and get the value in one step.

```
  }
  return static_cast<std::size_t>(-1);
}
```

this leads to this code:

```
std::size_t bin_search(std::vector<int> const& nums, int target) {
  auto front = nums.begin();
  auto end = nums.end();
  while(front!=end) {
    auto mid = front + (end-front)/2;

    if (*mid == target) { return mid-nums.begin(); }
    if (target > *mid) { front = std::next(mid); continue; }
    if (target < *mid) { end = mid; continue; }
  }
  return static_cast<std::size_t>(-1);
}
```

or, for more modern C++:

```
std::size_t bin_search(std::vector<int> const& nums, int target) {
  auto front = nums.begin();
  auto end = nums.end();
  while(front!=end) {
    auto mid = front + (end-front)/2;

    auto cmp = target <=> *mid;
    if (cmp == 0) { return mid-nums.begin(); }
    if (cmp > 0) { front = std::next(mid); continue; }
    if (cmp < 0) { end = mid; continue; }
  }
  return static_cast<std::size_t>(-1);
}
```

finally, note that I return `mid-begin()`, which is the index of the element in the range.

...

Moving it back to your index based code, odds are you have a problem with the range has exactly 1 element in it, because your code seems to not be using half-open intervals.  Your code looks like it uses closed intervals, where `nums[end]` remains part of your range.

A half-open interval contains its left-side fence post, but not its right-side fence post.  A bunch of algorithms work nicer if you use it.

Comment: This logic won't work, for vectors of size `N`, where `N` > 4, and `target` is at index `N/2-1` or `N/2+1`.

Comment: @WarmRed Sorry, I had a `std::prev` typo leftover from an earlier draft left in one of the 3 copies of the algorithm (and yes, that led to holes).  I have fixed it.  I also may have mixed up the `>` and `<` conditions - I have reordered them to target is always left, so the intervals should be more obvious.

Comment: Getting it right the first time is hard.  [Are you one of the 10% of programmers who can write a binary search?](https://reprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/are-you-one-of-the-10-percent/)

Comment: @MarkRansom It is.  But my problem came from mimicing the OP's code; my binary search is much simpler as I do the heavy lifting in a range view.